# Simple Database Views (update, insert, delete)

Tags: sql, view, corresponding-records

In my university notes I am currently attempting to study views but nowhere in the material is the criteria that shows when a simple view can be updated, inserted or deleted. I assume privileges can have a lot to do with this and seems like common sense to not allow data in a  view to be deleted by anyone other than the person who created the view but this isn't about common sense just is it possible to update, insert or delete a view and what is the criteria of that.

for my example I have created a view called `EmployeeName`s which takes the `first_name`, `last_name` under a new field `Name`s like so

```
CREATE VIEW EmployeeName as  
SELECT first_name + last_name "Names"
FROM Employees;
```

(not altogether sure of this syntax either but i think its right)

can this field be updated, inserted or deleted by anyone who has access to this view?(without privileges)

Comment: The rules may be different for different database systems.

Comment: Personally I would never do this through a view. Use a calculated column instead.

Comment: There is a whole book on the subject, by CJ Date: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028437.do

Answer (score 0):

There are certain conditions must be met, so that view could be updatable.
If you have, for example, an aggregate functions in view, you obviously cannot update it.

For Oracle more information you could find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/view-updatability.html)

[For MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-updatability.html) it's pretty similar to oracle

Comment: this is more a theoretical look on views not practical but we use oracle so for my example hypothetically i could do all three on this view but say i have another with an AVG operator this wouldnt work right?

Comment: Right, it would be non-updatable view.

Comment: greats thank you very much. Odd there isn't much information of this but that link is great

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server there are specific rules for updating views and they are very complicated. Each DB would do this differently.  Probably the majority of views I have seen over the years are unupdateable due to these rules.

Personally, I prefer to update tables directly and not through views. If you may have differnt database backends, tehyn I would defintely consider direct updating of tables instead as the rules are very differntfor each datbase.